# Solr nested documents _childDocuments_ and _root_ fields

Tags: solr, nested

Lets consider I have added the following document (chapter1) with 2 child documents (1-1) and (1-2) to my solr index using :

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?softCommit=true -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d ' [   {
    "id": "chapter1",
    "title" : "Indexing Child Documents in JSON",
    "content_type": "chapter",
    "_childDocuments_": [
      {
        "id": "1-1",
        "content_type": "page",
        "text": "ho hum... this is page 1 of chapter 1"
      },
      {
        "id": "1-2",
        "content_type": "page",
        "text": "more text... this is page 2 of chapter 1"
      }
    ]   } ] '
```

(source:http://heliosearch.org/solr-4-8-features/)

Is there a simple way to show, in solr web ui, the childDocuments of chapter1? 
I know I get the children of chapter1 using `{!child of=contenttype_s:chapter}id:chapter1`.

If I query `q=id:chapter1`, I get the fields: 'id', 'title' and 'content_type' but _childDocuments_ is not visible. It is not even in the solr web ui 'schema browser'.

I have a field named '_root_'. For children documents `1-1` and `1-2`, '_root_' is equal to `chapter1`. Which seems good. But I am surprised to see that document `chapter1` also as value `chapter1` in the '_root_' field. Is this normal?

I have tried to copy the content of _childDocuments_ into another field but I get the following error: '_childDocuments_' is not a glob and doesn't match any explicit field or dynamicField. Does this field exists somewhere or is it only used to create data for the _root_ field?